# Synchronize two SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sql-server-2008

I'm developing an application with C#. My database is SQL Server 2008. My application is installed on few remote PCs which are running on Windows XP or higher versions. I want all the local systems of those local PCs to sync with a main database which is located in another place. I have two ways in my mind to do that.

To connect to the distant SQL Server's database via internet and to do all the functions with database directly connecting to the main database.

To have a database on each PCs local SQL Server and do usual database operations of the system with local database and synchronize with the remote SQL Server's main database within some time period. Like once per an hour. Again connecting via internet.

Which one of these methods is more suitable? Or can anyone suggest me a better model?

Comment: What is the best solution depends entirely on the program and what it does, where it runs, how it's used, and other topics such as those. Based on the information you provide both methods are equally suitable. But for most applications that would hardly be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do is to use the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx). According to the link, the MSSF is

> A comprehensive synchronization platform that enables collaboration and offline access for applications, services, and devices with support for any data type, any data store, any transfer protocol, and any network topology.